# WCF Service not running without Administrator rights

Tags: wpf, wcf

I am new to WCF. I have a WCF service which I am hosting in a WPF application, while running the service it requires admin rights. Every time I have to right click the application which host my service and select "Run As Administrator". How can I make the service run on Windows 7?

Comment: If you want your program to automatically request admin right you have to add a manifest file and set the requestedExecutionLevel to requireAdministrator. This does not answer your question, but takes away the hassle of the right-click start as administrator procedure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I could not get what exactly my question was asking, but I got a workaround. Admin rights are needed only if you are using http bindings with WCF. I switched to netTcpBinding and it worked for me. It's not exactly what I asked, but worked for me. Maybe it will help someone facing similar issues.

Comment: jep, it has helped somebody ;-)

Comment: seems still not work for me either with NetTcpBinding

Comment: needs to set `binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;` to get to work

Answer (score 2):

Try using a higher port. Low ports may only be opend with administrative rights.

You might also have to use NETSH:

In cmd promt enter:

> NETSH
>
> add urlacl url=http://+:8732/ user=DOMAIN\user

Comment: I am using 8732 as port number, I am using HTTP bindings, Could that be a problem?

Comment: Thanks for your time, Sorry I was out on weekend, I just tried this, I am able to successfully run the command but my application still does not work without admin rights. I tried this netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:8732/[rest of the url] user=everyone. Is there anything wrong with this.